# need to 'reshape' dataframe

Tags: r, reshape

dataset:

```
      zip acs.pop napps    pperct cgrp zgrp      perc  
 1: 12007      97     2 2.0618557    2    1 25.000000  
 2: 12007      97     2 2.0618557   NA    2 50.000000  
 3: 12007      97     2 2.0618557    1    1 25.000000  
 4: 12008     485     2 0.4123711    2    1 33.333333  
 5: 12008     485     2 0.4123711    4    1 33.333333  
 6: 12008     485     2 0.4123711   NA    1 33.333333  
 7: 12009    7327   187 2.5522042    4   76 26.206897  
 8: 12009    7327   187 2.5522042    1   41 14.137931  
 9: 12009    7327   187 2.5522042    2   23  7.931034  
10: 12009    7327   187 2.5522042   NA  103 35.517241  
11: 12009    7327   187 2.5522042    3   47 16.206897  
12: 12010   28802   580 2.0137490   NA  275 32.163743  
13: 12010   28802   580 2.0137490    4  122 14.269006  
14: 12010   28802   580 2.0137490    1  269 31.461988  
15: 12010   28802   580 2.0137490    2   96 11.228070  
16: 12010   28802   580 2.0137490    3   93 10.877193  
17: 12018    7608   126 1.6561514    3   30 16.129032  
18: 12018    7608   126 1.6561514   NA   60 32.258065  
19: 12018    7608   126 1.6561514    2   14  7.526882  
20: 12018    7608   126 1.6561514    4   57 30.645161  
21: 12018    7608   126 1.6561514    1   25 13.440860  
22: 12019   14841   144 0.9702850   NA   62 30.097087  
23: 12019   14841   144 0.9702850    4   73 35.436893  
24: 12019   14841   144 0.9702850    3   30 14.563107  
25: 12019   14841   144 0.9702850    1   23 11.165049  
26: 12019   14841   144 0.9702850    2   18  8.737864  
27: 12020   31403   343 1.0922523    3   76 14.960630  
28: 12020   31403   343 1.0922523    1   88 17.322835  
29: 12020   31403   343 1.0922523    2   38  7.480315  
30: 12020   31403   343 1.0922523    4  141 27.755906  
31: 12020   31403   343 1.0922523   NA  165 32.480315  
32: 12022    1002     5 0.4990020   NA    4 44.444444  
33: 12022    1002     5 0.4990020    4    2 22.222222  
34: 12022    1002     5 0.4990020    3    1 11.111111  
35: 12022    1002     5 0.4990020    1    1 11.111111
```

I know the reshape2 or reshape package can handle this, but I'm not sure how.  I need the final output to look like this:

```
zip  acs.pop    napps   pperct  zgrp4   zgrp3   zgrp2   zgrp1   perc4   perc3   perc2   perc1  
12009   7327    187 2.5522042   76  47  23  41  26.206897   16.206897   7.931034    14.137931
```

zip is the id
acs.pop, napps, pperct will be the same for each zip group
zgrp4…zgrp1 are the values of zgrp for each value of cgrp
perc4…perc1 are the values of perc for each value of cgrp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a <s>good</s> use for `spread()` in `tidyr`.

```
df %>% filter(!is.na(cgrp)) %>% # if cgrp is missing I don't know where to put the obs
  gather(Var, Val,6:7) %>% # one row per measure (zgrp OR perc) observed
  group_by(zip, acs.pop, napps, pperct) %>% # unique combos of these will define rows in output
  unite(Var1,Var,cgrp) %>% # indentify which obs for which measure
  spread(Var1, Val) # make columns for zgrp_1, _2, etc., perc1,2, etc
```

Example output:

```
> df2[df2$zip==12009,]
Source: local data frame [1 x 12]

    zip acs.pop napps   pperct   perc_1   perc_2  perc_3  perc_4 zgrp_1 zgrp_2 zgrp_3 zgrp_4
1 12009    7327   187 2.552204 14.13793 7.931034 16.2069 26.2069     41     23     47     76
```

Thanks to @akrun for the assist

Comment: There is a typo in the first spread (pperct misses the t), anyway it doesn't look like the desired output.

Comment: perc = zgrp for each zip & cgrp / total for zgrp in the zip

Answer (score 5):

We can try `dcast` from the devel version of `data.table` which can take multiple `value.var` columns.  In this case, we have 'zgrp' and 'perc' are the value columns.  Using the grouping variables, we create an sequence variable ('ind') and then use `dcast` to convert from 'long' to 'wide' format.

Instructions to install the devel version are [`here`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)

```
 library(data.table)#v1.9.5
 setDT(df1)[, ind:= 1:.N, .(zip, acs.pop, napps, pperct)]
 dcast(df1, zip+acs.pop + napps+pperct~ind, value.var=c('zgrp', 'perc'))
 #     zip acs.pop napps    pperct 1_zgrp 2_zgrp 3_zgrp 4_zgrp 5_zgrp   1_perc
#1: 12007      97     2 2.0618557      1      2      1     NA     NA 25.00000
#2: 12008     485     2 0.4123711      1      1      1     NA     NA 33.33333
#3: 12009    7327   187 2.5522042     76     41     23    103     47 26.20690
#4: 12010   28802   580 2.0137490    275    122    269     96     93 32.16374
#5: 12018    7608   126 1.6561514     30     60     14     57     25 16.12903
#6: 12019   14841   144 0.9702850     62     73     30     23     18 30.09709
#7: 12020   31403   343 1.0922523     76     88     38    141    165 14.96063
#8: 12022    1002     5 0.4990020      4      2      1      1     NA 44.44444
#     2_perc    3_perc   4_perc    5_perc
#1: 50.00000 25.000000       NA        NA
#2: 33.33333 33.333333       NA        NA
#3: 14.13793  7.931034 35.51724 16.206897
#4: 14.26901 31.461988 11.22807 10.877193
#5: 32.25807  7.526882 30.64516 13.440860
#6: 35.43689 14.563107 11.16505  8.737864
#7: 17.32284  7.480315 27.75591 32.480315
#8: 22.22222 11.111111 11.11111        NA
```

Or we can use `ave/reshape` from `base R`

```
 df2 <- transform(df1, ind=ave(seq_along(zip), zip,
                 acs.pop, napps, pperct, FUN=seq_along))
 reshape(df2, idvar=c('zip', 'acs.pop', 'napps', 'pperct'),
                               timevar='ind', direction='wide')
```

Comment: whoah.  this is for real?

Comment: @C8H10N4O2  The OP should have showed the full expected output instead of a single line.

Comment: I didn't know that data.table package has a `dcast` function like the `reshape`'s `dcast`!

Comment: Akrun...your answer is obviously correct in spite of my errors in my result example, but why does the devel datatable version accomplish what final datatable doesn't?

Comment: @user3067851 It is a recent addition in the devel version, which will any time be released in CRAN.

Comment: Having to create this index column comes up quite often.. Will have to figure out a way to do this directly in `data.table::dcast`.

Comment: @Arun Yes, if there is an argument in `dcast`, it will be great

Comment: akrun, tried your DT solution because the base solution takes very long and even caused my R to crash. However, this is the error I received:                                                                                                       > setDT(zip.pene)[,ind :=1:.N, .(zip, acs.pop,napps, pperct)] 
> dcast(zip.pene, zip + acs.pop + napps + pperct ~ ind, value.var = c('zgrp', 'perc'))Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : subscript out of bounds
In addition: Warning message:
In if (!(value.var %in% names(data))) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Comment: @user3067851  As I mentioned in the post, it is based on the devel version of data.table.  I am not sure whether you are using that.  Also, my solution is based on the example you showed.  Are you getting the error based on the same example as in the post?  If not, it is better to post a small example (preferably dput output) that gives this error.